# How to change PreferenceHandler string value into IntetService

Tags: android, intentservice

I m building an InterService. This service getting data from bluetooth device.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.MyDialog;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.R;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.apiRequest.iotrequests.DosimeterDataRequest;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.datasyncingjobs.DosimeterSyncingJob;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.dosimeter.protocol.BLEUtils;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.dosimeter.protocol.CRC8Calculator;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.dosimeter.protocol.MeasurementConverter;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.dosimeter.protocol.PolismartConstants;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.utils.AppConstants;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.utils.Global;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.utils.PreferenceHandler;
import com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.utils.Utilities;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.UUID;

public class DosimeterDataSensingService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "DosimeterDataSensingService";
    public static boolean isStarted = false;
    private MeasurementConverter measurementConvertor;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mStatus;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    private BluetoothGatt mConnGatt;
    private boolean notificationsEnabled;
    private long dosimeterScanningTime;
    private boolean isThreadStarted = false;
    private List<DosimeterDataRequest.DataBean> dosimeterDataList;
    private DosimeterDataRequest dosimeterDataRequest;
    private String macAddress;
    private boolean isRecordingEnabled = false;
    private String dose = "";
    private int battery = -1;

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public DosimeterDataSensingService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public DosimeterDataSensingService() {
        super(null);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        dosimeterDataRequest = new DosimeterDataRequest();
        dosimeterDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        mContext = this;
        measurementConvertor = new MeasurementConverter(this);
        String scanningTime = PreferenceHandler.readString(this, PreferenceHandler.DOSIMETER_SCANNING_TIME, null);
        Log.i("SCANNINGTIME", scanningTime);
        if (scanningTime == null) {
            dosimeterScanningTime = 0;
        } else {
            dosimeterScanningTime = Long.parseLong(scanningTime);
        }
        String mac = PreferenceHandler.readString(this, PreferenceHandler.DM_MAC, null);
        if (mac != null) {
            connectDosimeter(mac);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = createNotificationChannel();
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logoxhdpi)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setContentTitle("Cardio App")
                .setContentText("Getting data from Dosimeter")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        startForeground((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() + 1), notification);
        isStarted = true;

        if (PreferenceHandler.readString(this, PreferenceHandler.TYPE_USER, null).equals("2")) {
            checkDosage();
        }

        checkBattery();

    }

    Intent isBatteryLow = new Intent(AppConstants.ACTION_LOW_BATTERY_RECEIVED);



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isStarted = false;
        disconnectDosimeter();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    /**
     * connect dosimeter
     *
     * @param mac mac address of dosimeter
     */
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    private void connectDosimeter(String mac) {
        macAddress = mac;
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dosimeter connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("Global:: ", "Dosimeter Service Started");
        mStatus = BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED;
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = com.example.dcubeandroid.dietcontrol.zephyerble.BLEUtils.getAdapter();
        isRecordingEnabled = true;
        mDevice = adapter.getRemoteDevice(mac);
        if (mDevice == null) {
            mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DosimeterConstants.ACTION_DOSIMETER_DISCONNECTED));
        } else
            // connect to Gatt
            if ((mConnGatt == null) && (mStatus == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED)) {
                // try to connect
                /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    mConnGatt = mDevice.connectGatt(mContext, false, mBluetoothGattCallback, 2);
                } else {*/
                mConnGatt = mDevice.connectGatt(mContext, false, mBluetoothGattCallback);
                //}
                mStatus = BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING;
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Dosimeter connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                if (mConnGatt != null) {
                    // re-connect and re-discover Services
                    mConnGatt.connect();
                    mConnGatt.discoverServices();
                    //mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DosimeterConstants.ACTION_DOSIMETER_DISCONNECTED));

                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "state error");
                    disconnectionHandler.postDelayed(disconnectionRunnable, dosimeterScanningTime);
                    //  Toast.makeText(this, "Dosimeter connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    }

    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic infoCharacteristic;
    /**
     * bluetooth gatt callback
     */
    private BluetoothGattCallback mBluetoothGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                mStatus = newState;
                mConnGatt.discoverServices();
                //broadcast about connection
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                mStatus = newState;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            int i = 0;
            for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
                if ((service == null) || (service.getUuid() == null)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (DosimeterConstants.SERVICE_IMMEDIATE_ALERT.equalsIgnoreCase(service.getUuid().toString())) {
                    infoCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(DosimeterConstants.CHAR_ALERT_LEVEL));
                }

                //get charactersticks of third service...............
                if (i == 2)
                    getCharacterSticsOfLastService(service, gatt, i);
                i++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                if (DosimeterConstants.READ_DATA_INSTRUMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                    byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
                    if (CRC8Calculator.getCRC8(value, value.length) == value[0]) {
                        readStatusPacket(value);
                        //send notify write command
                        boolean submitted = BLEUtils.SetNotificationForCharacteristic(gatt, characteristic, notificationsEnabled ? BLEUtils.Notifications.DISABLED : BLEUtils.Notifications.NOTIFY);
                        if (submitted) {
                            notificationsEnabled = !notificationsEnabled;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            Log.i(TAG, "on characteristicChanged=" + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
            if (DosimeterConstants.READ_DATA_INSTRUMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
                byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
                if (CRC8Calculator.getCRC8(value, value.length) == value[0]) {
                    readStatusPacket(value);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void getCharacterSticsOfLastService(BluetoothGattService service, BluetoothGatt gatt, int i) {
        BluetoothGattService blueToothGattService = service == null ? gatt.getServices().get(i) : gatt.getService(service.getUuid());
        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = blueToothGattService.getCharacteristics();
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic bluetoothGattCharacteristic : characteristics) {
            gatt.readCharacteristic(bluetoothGattCharacteristic);
            // the engine parses through the data of the btgattcharac and returns a wrapper characteristic
            // the wrapper characteristic is matched with accepted bt gatt profiles, provides field types/values/units
            // Characteristic charact = Engine.getInstance().getCharacteristic(bluetoothGattCharacteristic.getUuid());
        }
    }

    /**
     * read packet data for status
     *
     * @param paramArrayOfByte packet data in form of byte array
     */
    private void readStatusPacket(byte[] paramArrayOfByte) {

    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    public void disconnectDosimeter() {


        Log.v("Dosimeter", "isRecordingEnabled" + isRecordingEnabled);
        Log.v("Dosimeter", "Disconnecteddd");
    }



}
```

Now this IntentService use this variable :

```
 String scanningTime = PreferenceHandler.readString(this, PreferenceHandler.DOSIMETER_SCANNING_TIME, null);
```

Now when the service is started, I want to change the values of this "scanningTime".
So I m build this code in another class:

```
String dosimeterScanningTime = "newValue";
  PreferenceHandler.writeString(getApplicationContext(), PreferenceHandler.DOSIMETER_SCANNING_TIME, dosimeterScanningTime!=null ? dosimeterScanningTime.toString() : null);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                        stopService(new Intent(this, DosimeterDataSensingService.class));
                        startForegroundService(new Intent(this, DosimeterDataSensingService.class));
                    } else {
                        stopService(new Intent(this, DosimeterDataSensingService.class));
                        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DosimeterDataSensingService.class));
                    }
```

Now the code works without issue or exception but If I don't restart my application the value of "scanningTime" in my IntentService is not changed.

If I restarted the application, scanningTime = newValue.

How can I fixed them?